# How to create url to edit form of a specific list item?

Tags: 2013, edit-form

I would like to create a url to a list item edit form.
It is possible to use:
https://sharepoint/site/Lists/MyList/EditForm.aspx?ID=1

and
https://sharepoint/site/Lists/MyList/EditForm.aspx?Title=Test1

but this doesn't work:
https://sharepoint/site/Lists/MyList/EditForm.aspx?OtherColumn=OtherValue

Any ideas how to create a link to edit form which has a specific value in a specific column?

Comment: Are you creating the link using calculated column?

Comment: Yes, a calculated column to another list.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom Edit Form in SharePoint Designer and edit it to add a custom ParameterBinding for you QueryString. Then use the parameter to filter the datasource, in SelectCommand, to get your item.

https://sharepoint/site/Lists/MyList/**CustomForm**.aspx?OtherColumn=OtherValue

But I'm not sure it's a good thing doing this. You need to ensure the uniqueness of you column value, otherwise you can have people editing the wrong item.